# How to register (or login) in Whatsapp using Python

Tags: python, registration, whatsapp

I am new to Python. 
I need to register in Whatsapp. 
I found a library [**`Yowsup`**](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup).
But I can't understand how to use it. 
I am creating a service in `Django` and python and I need to write a function for registration, how to do it?
Like:
`def Register():`

I have found an example in `Yowsup`, but it is for console, how to use it in web service ?

Comment: You can use `selenium`.

Comment: It should works on Python web server, so, as I understand, Selenium is not ok :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this site.   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywhatsapp/

Simple wrapper around yowsup to send a message or mediafile with whatsapp

## Example usage

You can register a whatsapp client with the [yowsup-cli](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0#yowsup-cli-registration)

```python

````
`from whatsapp import Client

phone_to = '31641371199'

client = Client(login='3161516888', password='secretpasswordbase64')
client.send_message(phone_to, 'Hello Lola')
client.send_media(phone_to, path='/Users/tax/Desktop/logo.jpg')

```

# Installation
```
$ pip install pywhatsapp
```
````

Comment: Can you help me? It needs a password for authorization, but how can I get it?